# Segmentation fault in a multithreaded clients/server prototype

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, pthreads

I am developing a prototype of an algorithm that works on a set of nodes where each node maintains a connection to all other nodes and sends messages.

In order to send a message, the node sends it is fixed-size header first and then the data.

After a lot of work, I concluded that the problem is with the multi-threaded programming part of the code. Thus, I created this code as a PoC.

This prototype is designed to have one server with several clients of a number defined during compilation.

A server is in charge of listening to some clients each on a separate thread. Since this is just a prototype, we the drop the data.

Each client sends data into the server in two steps: Header then body using `send_message`.

By the way, this algorithm should produce data on a specific bandwidth benchmark from each client to the server. By default, each client sends 100Mb/s data to the server.

The code comprises:

## client.cpp:

```
#include "network.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int sockfd;

    std::cout << "HEADER: " << HEADER << std::endl;

    // Read the server's IP
    struct hostent *server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);

    // Read the arguments from console
    get_client_arguments (argc, argv);

    // Connect to the server
    sockfd = connect_to_server(server);

    sleep (1);

    // Start sending (Start the experiment)
    multi_unicaster (sockfd);

    close (sockfd);

    return 0;
}

/**********************************************/

void usage (char *argv){

    std::cout << "usage: " << argv << " hostname [-p port] [-t throughput]" << std::endl;
    exit(0);
}

/**********************************************/
```

## server.cpp:

```
#include "network.h"

/**********************************************/

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    std::cout << "HEADER: " << HEADER << std::endl;
    get_server_arguments(argc, argv);

    // Create several threads to listen for incoming connections
    // and read data from several clients simultaneously
    start_listening_threads ();

    return 0;
}

/**********************************************/

void usage (char *argv){

    std::cout << "usage: " << argv << " [-p port]" << std::endl;
    exit(0);
}

/**********************************************/
```

## message.h:

```
#ifndef __MESSAGE__
#define __MESSAGE__

#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include "func.h"

/***************************************/

// The header structure
typedef struct {

    // Message ID
    unsigned mID;

    // IP of sender
    struct in_addr sender;

    // Message sie
    size_t datasize;

}header_type;

/***************************************/

#define HEADER sizeof(header_type)

/***************************************/

/*
 * Message Class
 */
class message
{
    private:
        // Message header
        header_type * header;

        // Message text
        byte * text;

    public:

        // Message Accessors, mutators and related functions
        byte * get_text();
        header_type * get_header();
        void set_datasize(size_t);
        size_t get_datasize();
        struct in_addr get_sender();
        void set_ID(unsigned);
        unsigned get_ID();
        void print();

        message(int,struct in_addr,size_t);
        message(header_type *, size_t);
        ~message();

        message & operator = (const message&);
        message(const message&);
};
#endif


/***************************************/

extern std::queue <message * > sending_messages_queue;

/***************************************/
/*
 * Constructor used for initializing complete messages
 * 
 */

message::message(int ID,struct in_addr IP,size_t d_s){

    header = (header_type *) malloc (HEADER);

    header -> mID = ID;
    header -> datasize = d_s;
    header -> sender.s_addr = IP.s_addr;

    if (d_s > 0){
        text = (byte *) malloc (d_s);
        memset (text, '.', d_s);
    }
    else text = NULL;
}

/***************************************/
/*
 * Copy constructor (Initialize)
 * 
 */

message::message(const message& other){

    header = (header_type *) malloc (HEADER);

    std::memcpy (header, other.header, HEADER);

    if (header -> datasize > 0){
        text = (byte *) malloc (header -> datasize);
        std::memcpy (text, other.text, header -> datasize);
    } else
        text = NULL;
}

/***************************************/
/*
 * destructor
 *
 * Message destructor
 */

message::~message() {
    if (text != NULL){
        free(text);
        text = NULL;
    }
}

/***************************************/
/*
 * Assignment operator (Update)
 * 
 */

message & message::operator = (const message& other) {

    header = (header_type *) malloc (HEADER);

    std::memcpy (header, other.header, HEADER);

    if (header -> datasize >0){
        text = (byte *) malloc (header -> datasize);
        std::memcpy (text, other.text, header -> datasize);
    } else
        text = NULL;

    return *this;
}

/***************************************/

/*
* another constructor
*
*/

message::message(header_type *h, size_t s){

    header = (header_type *) malloc (HEADER);

    std::memcpy (header, h, HEADER);

    if (s > 0){
        text = (byte *) malloc (s);
        std::memset (text, '.', s);
    } else
        text = NULL;
}

/***************************************/

/*
* get_header
*
* Header accessor
*/

header_type * message::get_header(){
    return header;
}

/***************************************/

/*
* get_text
*
* Text accessor
*/

byte * message::get_text(){
    return text;
}

/***************************************/

/*
* get_sender
*
* Sender IP accessor
*/

struct in_addr message::get_sender(){
    return header -> sender;
}

/***************************************/

/*
* get_datasize
*
* datasize accessor
*/

size_t message::get_datasize(){
    return header -> datasize;
}

/***************************************/

/*
* set_ID
*
* ID mutator
*/
void message::set_ID(unsigned ID) {
    header -> mID = ID;
}

/***************************************/

/*
* get_ID
*
* ID Accessor
*/
unsigned message::get_ID() {
    return header -> mID;
}

/***************************************/

/*
* set_datasize
*
* datasize mutator
*/
void message::set_datasize(size_t d) {
    header -> datasize = d;
}

/***************************************/

/*
* print
*
*/
void message::print() {
    std::cout << header -> mID << "," << inet_ntoa (header -> sender)  << "," << header -> datasize;

    std::cout << std::endl;
}

/***************************************/
```

## func.h:

```
// Some support functions

using namespace std;

/***********************************************************************/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <math.h>

/***********************************************************************/

typedef uint8_t byte;
const unsigned long kilo = 1024;
const unsigned long mega = 1024 * kilo;
const unsigned long giga = 1024 * mega;
const unsigned MESSAGE_SIZE = 10 * kilo;

/***********************************************************************/

int port = 4444;
int throughput = 100;
int newsockfd [CLIENTS];

/***********************************************************************/

void usage (char *argv);

/***********************************************************************/

/* 
 * 
 * subtract_time
 * 
 * Subtracts time to handle negative values
 * 
 */

struct timeval subtract_time (struct timeval * left_operand, struct timeval * right_operand){

    struct timeval res;

    if (left_operand -> tv_sec >= right_operand -> tv_sec){
        if (left_operand -> tv_usec >= right_operand -> tv_usec){

            res.tv_sec = left_operand -> tv_sec - right_operand -> tv_sec;
            res.tv_usec = left_operand -> tv_usec - right_operand -> tv_usec;
        }else{
            res.tv_sec = left_operand -> tv_sec - right_operand -> tv_sec - 1;
            res.tv_usec = 1000000 + left_operand -> tv_usec - right_operand -> tv_usec;
        }
    }

    return res;
}

/***********************************************************************/

void get_server_arguments (int argc, char *argv[]){

    int i = 1;
    while (i < argc){

        if (strcmp (argv [i], "-p") ==0){

            port = atoi (argv [i + 1]);
            i+= 2;
        }
        else usage (argv [0]);
    }
}

/***********************************************************************/

void get_client_arguments (int argc, char *argv[]){

    int i = 2;

    while (i < argc){

        if (strcmp (argv [i], "-p") ==0){

            port = atoi (argv [i + 1]);
            i+= 2;
        }

        else if (strcmp (argv [i], "-t") ==0){

            throughput = atoi (argv [i + 1]);
            i+= 2;
        }
        else usage (argv [0]);
    }
}

/***********************************************************************/

void print_bandwidth(unsigned long long sz){

    double size;

    if (sz > giga){

        // Round result and show two decimal values
        size = round (sz / (giga /1000));
        std::cout << size /1000 << " Gb/s"<< std::endl;
    }
    else if (sz > mega){

        // Round result and show two decimal values
        size = round (sz / (mega /100));
        std::cout << size /100 << " Mb/s"<< std::endl;
    }
    else if (sz > kilo){

        // Round result and show one decimal value
        size = round (sz /( kilo /10));
        std::cout << size /10 << " Kb/s"<< std::endl;
    }
    else{
        std::cout << sz << " b/s"<< std::endl;
    }
}

/***********************************************************************/
```

## network.h:

```
// Network related functions

#include "message.h"
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

/***********************************************************************/

void read_message (int);
int accept_connection (int);
void * listening (void *);

/***********************************************************************/

unsigned burst_size;
bool NAGLE = false;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
struct timeval recent_elapsed_time_val {0,0};
struct timeval start_tv;
int initial_listening_socket;
unsigned connections = 0;

/***********************************************************************/

void listen_for_connections (){

    // Server: Listens for connections from clients
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

    initial_listening_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (initial_listening_socket < 0)
        std::cerr << "ERROR opening socket";
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    if (bind(initial_listening_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
        std::cerr << "ERROR on binding"<<std::endl;

    listen(initial_listening_socket,CLIENTS);
}

/***********************************************************************/

int accept_connection (){

    // Server: Accepts connections from client
    int newsockfd;
    socklen_t clilen;
    struct sockaddr_in cli_addr;

    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

    std::cout << "waiting for new connection .." << std::endl; 
    newsockfd = accept(initial_listening_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);

    std::cout << "received new connection .." << std::endl;

    connections ++;

    if (connections == CLIENTS)
        close(initial_listening_socket);

    return newsockfd;
}

/***********************************************************************/

int connect_to_server(struct hostent *server){

    // Client: Connects to server
    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (sockfd < 0)
        std::cerr << "ERROR opening socket";

    if (server == NULL){
        std::cerr << stderr << "ERROR, no such host"<< std::endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    int flag;
    if (NAGLE) flag = 0;
    else flag = 1;

    if (setsockopt (sockfd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (char *) &flag, sizeof(int)) ==-1){
        perror ("ERROR on setting TCP_NODELAY!");
        std::terminate ();
    }

    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr,(char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port);

    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
        std::cerr <<"ERROR connecting"<< std::endl;

    return sockfd;
}


/***********************************************************************/

void start_listening_threads (){

    // Server: Creates listening threads
    pthread_t listening_thread [CLIENTS];

    listen_for_connections ();

    for(unsigned i=0;i< CLIENTS;i++){

        unsigned * arg = (unsigned *) malloc(sizeof(*arg));

        if ( arg == NULL ) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't allocate memory for thread arg.\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        *arg = i;

        pthread_create(&listening_thread[i], NULL,(void* (*)(void*))&listening, arg);
    }

    for(unsigned i=0;i< CLIENTS;i++){

        pthread_join (listening_thread[i], NULL);
    }
}

/***********************************************************************/

void * listening (void *a){

    // Server: Start listening after establishing a connection with the client
    int i = *((int *) a);

    newsockfd [i] = accept_connection ();

    while (1){

        read_message (newsockfd [i]);
    }

    return NULL;
}

/***********************************************************************/

void measure_throughput(unsigned counter){

    // Client: Tracks throughput and keeps on the wanted threshold
    struct timeval current_time;

    // Get the current time in order to track the throughput
    gettimeofday (&current_time, NULL);
    struct timeval elapsed_time_val = subtract_time (&current_time, &start_tv);

    double elapsed = elapsed_time_val.tv_sec+ (elapsed_time_val.tv_usec/1000000.0);

    unsigned long long sent_bytes = counter * (MESSAGE_SIZE + HEADER);
    if (elapsed > 0){

        // Calculate the expected time to send sent_bytes
        double theoretical_time = (sent_bytes) / ((throughput * mega) / 8.0);

        // Compare the expected time with the real elapsed time
        if (theoretical_time > elapsed){
            __useconds_t additional_time = (theoretical_time - elapsed) * 1000000;
            usleep (additional_time);
        }
    }

    if (elapsed_time_val.tv_sec > recent_elapsed_time_val.tv_sec){
        unsigned sending_throughput = (unsigned)((sent_bytes * 8) / (mega * elapsed * 1.0));
        std::cout << "throughput: " << sending_throughput << std::endl;
        recent_elapsed_time_val = elapsed_time_val;
    }
}

/***********************************************************************/

void send_message (message * m, int sockfd){

    // Client: Send on message header then data.
    if (write (sockfd, m -> get_header(), HEADER) == -1){

        perror ("Error exporting Header to socket");
        close (sockfd);
        exit (1);
    }

    if (write (sockfd, m -> get_text (), MESSAGE_SIZE) == -1){

        perror ("Error exporting Header to socket");
        close (sockfd);
        exit (1);
    }
}

/***********************************************************************/

void read_message (int sockfd){

    // Server: Listens for one message header then text.
    int receivedPackage = 0;
    int pos = 0;
    int expected_bytes = HEADER;
    header_type header;

    while (expected_bytes >0){

        if ((receivedPackage = read(sockfd, &header + pos, expected_bytes)) < 0){
            perror ("ERROR importing message header from socket!");
            std::terminate();
        }
        pos += receivedPackage;
        expected_bytes -= receivedPackage;
    }

    if (header.datasize != MESSAGE_SIZE){
        message * m = new message (&header, (size_t)0);
        m-> print ();
    }

    pos = 0;
    receivedPackage = 0;
    expected_bytes = MESSAGE_SIZE;
    byte text [MESSAGE_SIZE];

    while (expected_bytes >0){

        if ((receivedPackage = read(sockfd, text + pos, expected_bytes)) < 0){
            perror ("ERROR importing message header from socket!");
            std::terminate();
        }
        pos += receivedPackage;
        expected_bytes -= receivedPackage;
    }
}

/***********************************************************************/

void multi_unicaster (int sockfd){

    unsigned counter=0;

    gettimeofday (&start_tv, NULL);

    while (1){

        counter ++;

        struct in_addr IP;

        inet_aton ("127.0.0.1",&IP);

        message * m = new message (counter, IP, MESSAGE_SIZE);

        if (m -> get_datasize () != MESSAGE_SIZE)
            m-> print ();

        send_message (m,sockfd);

        delete m;

        measure_throughput(counter);
    }
}

/***********************************************************************/
```

## Makefile:

```
all: server client

FLAGS=-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -pthread $(ARGS) -std=c++11 -g -rdynamic -lpthread
CXXFLAGS=$(DEF) $(FLAGS)

output/%.o: %.cpp
    g++ $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

client: output/client.o
    g++ $(FLAGS) -o $@ $^

server: output/server.o
    g++ $(FLAGS) -o $@ $^

clean:
    rm -rf output/* *~ server client
```

When running the code on the loopback, everything goes right, however when testing it on apart servers (indeed, apart datacenters) sometimes it is working without any problem and others not.

If the received data is right, the received header should be right. To verify that the received data is not faulty, the `datasize` received in the header should be correct (i.e. 10 * kilo) otherwise the data is messed up.

This verification is provided in `read_message` function in `network.h` where I guess is the problem.

I provided all this code should somebody need to test it.

Comment: What is the problem? What happens? What does not happen? What needs to happen? We cannot read your mind, and it's hard to find a problem if we don't know what we're looking for...

Comment: I hope your server doesn't accept more clients than the CPU cores it has... running all these threads slows you down due to excessive context switches... Why not use existing libraries?

Comment: @Mohamad-jaafar Is there any way you could [downsize the code any](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? It doesn't appear to be as small as it could be, so it may be hard for some readers to understand the problem and create a good answer for your question.

Comment: @Myst I am using this code just with few clients usually less than 10. As for libraries, I guess the problem is with mixing up data not with the selection. By the way the code is facing the same problem even with select.

Comment: @IsiahMeadows I will try to do it

Comment: You Write : 'sometimes it is working without any problem and others not.' I still don't know what the problem is. Does your program crash? Do you get an error message? Is there no data received? Is there faulty data received?

Comment: @Mohamad-jaafar Also, might I mention that it is a potential DoS vulnerability? Even if you'll never have more than maybe 4 concurrent users in practice, it might be a good idea anyways to cut down on thread usage, just in case.

Comment: @DrDonut I added the problem at the end lines now.

Comment: @IsiahMeadows, would you please explain much more, I am not sure I have figured out.

Comment: Another thought, the message header type is non-portable architecture dependent. On some architectures `unsigned` and `size_t` might have 32 bit, on others they might have 64bits or 16bits... also, `struct in_addr` is implementation specific (which OS does the server run on)? ... Unless you're sure all the nodes run on the same OS and architecture, consider using byte streams and bit specific types (i.e. `uint64_t` and `uint8_t client_addr[16]`... as well as network order bytes for the numeric data.

Comment: thanks @orbitcowboy, I will check it now

Comment: @Myst you are great man, this might be the problem.

Comment: @Mohamad-jaafar, you're very welcome. I hope this resolves the issue. I'll post a detailed answer so other people with similar issues could have a fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm posting an answer I gave in the comments, in case it should help someone experiencing a similar issue.

The message header type in the code looks like this:

```
typedef struct {
    // Message ID
    unsigned mID;
    // IP of sender
    struct in_addr sender;
    // Message size
    size_t datasize;
} header_type;
```

This message header type is non-portable and architecture dependent.

On some architectures unsigned and size_t might have 32 bit, on others they might have 64bits or 16bits...

Also, struct `in_addr` is implementation specific, so the message header might look different on different operating systems (which OS does the server run on? which version?).

Unless all the network nodes (servers and clients) run on the same OS and architecture, there's a need for byte streams and bit specific types (i.e. `uint64_t datasize` and `uint8_t client_addr[16]`.

Another related issue would be the architecture (vs. network) byte order for the message size.

Different architectures exhibit different [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), so it's important to make sure the message length is stored and read correctly.

I would consider a `union` for the message size, or limiting the message size length to 32 bits (`uint32_t`), so I could use the POSIX [network byte order API](http://linux.die.net/man/3/byteorder).

```
typedef struct {
    // Network byte ordered Message ID
    uint32_t nb_mID;
    // IP of sender as either a IPv4 string or a IPv6 string 39
    uint8_t sender[39];
    // IPv4 vs. IPv6 data identifier
    uint8_t sender_type;
    // Network byte ordered Message size
    uint32_t nb_datasize;
} header_type;
```

**Side Note**

As a side note, it should be mentioned that using a thread per connection design causes slowdowns due to excessive context switches and could make the server more susceptible toDoS attacks.

Normally, running more threads (or processes) then the number of CPU cores would lead to excessive context switches.

This is usually acceptable to some extent due to other considerations, but a thread per connection would run down system resources very fast and the system could easily reach a point where it is spending more time on context switches then task performance.

Comment: The real problem was with serialization. In addition, you have added a point.